# Cannot start IIS default site (version 7)

Tags: iis-7, localhost

I am developing on my local machine (Windows 7), and using IIS 7. I usually create a new website by right clicking on sites -> Add New Site. Then do the usual stuff by pointing to the physical files, and I'd stop all other websites which I didnt need. I could then run the site on port 80 without any binding conflicts.

I then recently started doing some ASP.NET development. When I published from my VS 2010 to local host I could run the website, and it all worked great. I then stopped the site (asp.net) but I couldnt start any of the other sites (not even the default). I am not sure why.

I started to read about App Pools and someone said to remove all the application pools. So I removed all my application pools (except the default app pool), and I also removed all the websites (as they had a red x next to them).

I now cannot start the default site as the restart, start and stop are greyed out. I cannot find out any way to reset the IIS server. One error I have received is;
the object identifier does not represent a valid object iis7

I dont know really know what this means, and when I search for this error it seems that many people have come across this error but in different contexts.

Is there any way to reset IIS so I can build simple websites again? Do I need to uninstall IIS and reInstall?

Comment: This happened to me when deploying a previously working application on IIS (7). I could not create new app pools and start them, or create a new website. Resetting IIS fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall IIS and reinstall would probably be the easiest and fastest way to accomplish this.

Other than that check the event logs see if you can find any clues there.

Comment: Thanks Ralf. I tried to reinstall but when it starts up it's still grey. I cannot restart/start/stop the default site.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to ensure there is a one-to-one relationship between the number of sites & the app pools that host them.  If they are 32-bit apps hosted on a 64-bit server, you'll need to enable this property (set it to True) on the app pool you want to use for your site.  You'll want to run:
C:\inetpub\AdminScripts>cscript adsutil SET W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32bitapponWin64 1

The .NET Framework obviously needs to be installed, but then the separate step of running the ASP installation command needs to be done (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.xxxx\aspnet_regiis.exe -i). If it already is, re-install them - it could be malfunctioning/corrupt.

After all that, I noticed IIS 7 puts on this generic app pool identity account to run the app pool with.  I created a service account, gave this account Admin rights just to see if the site would run, and added it onto the app pool as the "Custom account".  I no longer get the HTTP 503 error.  The account should have the "Log on as a service" and "Log on as a batch job" rights.  If it will be using impersonation and going out to a SQL database, the "Impersonate client after authentication" and "Allow log on locally" rights are also needed (hence why I like just giving it admin privileges to see if it works, first).